# Converting Function Address to 64-bit Integer: Undefined/Ill-behaved?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

Background: I have a scenario in which I must allow comparison between two functor objects, using a unique ID to test if they're equal (I can't simply check if their addresses are the same, as the function pointers themselves aren't stored in the object). Initially, I had this idea, to simply start the id generator at 0 and increment ad infinitum:

```
struct GenerateUniqueID{
    static std::size_t id_count = 0;

    auto operator()() -> std::size_t { return (id_count++); }
};
```

...However, as I have literally thousands upon thousands of these objects created every few seconds, I actually managed to run into the case of id_count overflowing back to 0! The results were... unpleasant. Now, the second idea I had was that, since these functors are, obviously, wrappers around a function, I could perform the comparison by converting the address of the function pointer into a 64-bit integer, and storing that in the class for comparison. See:

```
//psuedocode
struct Functor{
    std::uint64_t id;

    auto generate_id_from_function_address(function f) -> void {
        id = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t>(&f);
    }
};
```

**Now, my concern here is simple: is casting function pointers to 64-bit integers ill-behaved/undefined? On 32-bit architectures? On 64-bit architectures? On both?** My main concern here is with virtual functions, as I know that for inline functions the compiler simply creates a non-inlined version, so there's no issue there.

Comment: You think you overflowed a 64-bit counter? At 4 billion increments per second, that would take over a century...

Comment: `converting the address of the function pointer into a 64-bit integer, and storing that in the class for comparison` Why not store an actual function pointer?

Comment: Nemo, I am aiming for compatability with 32-bit OSes. @IgorTandetnik: There's no standard-compliant way to store a single function pointer to a member function and/or a static function

Comment: `My main concern here is with virtual functions` Are you talking about member functions? A pointer-to-member is typically 16 bytes or even 32 bytes large. If you aren't talking about member functions but of regular standalone functions, then what do you mean by "virtual function"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You must be storing a function pointer in **some** form. If you don't store it, how do you plan to call it? If you don't plan to call it, then what's the point of the exercise? Color me confused.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I am talking of member functions that have to cope with v-tables, yes. I have no knowledge of how virtual functions work internally, besides the fact that they contain some offset into said table. As for your second question, I do not store the function pointer; I have several templated functions, all accepting different types of function pointers (static, member, const-member, etc.), that are then passed to a delegate class. Essentially, I only have access to these pointers while I'm passing them through to the delegate. Sorry for any ambiguities.

Comment: What do you need an ID for, then? You say you "must allow comparison between two functor objects" - but what does it mean for two stateless objects to be equal or not equal? You can have them pass through the same pointer one day, and different pointers another day, can't you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I must store them in a standard container, for later retrieval. By "storing" their addresses as 64-bit integers, I can do comparisons to see if two objects point to the same function, allowing me to perform finding operations.

Comment: Who is "them" in this sentence - function pointers or wrappers? If the latter, then why do you need to store, or retrieve, an object that doesn't carry any information? You say you need to check if "two objects point to the same function" - but if they don't actually store function pointers, in what sense do they "point" to any particular function? This just doesn't add up.

Comment: As [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (thankfully) does not override `operator &`, the the only think you're taking the "address" of in this code is an automatic variable (the parameter `f`). Seems somewhat pointless in the long run, as the actually *callable* within is not even considered.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I am not referring to std::function; I am talking about function pointers themselves. Ignor Tandetnik: I am talking of the wrappers; the delegates- the things that the wrappers are wrapping- actually store the function pointers, but they provide no way to compare two delegates. Before I pass the function pointer to the delegate, I would like to save its address as in integer, so that I may perform the comparison myself.

Comment: Pointer is 32bit or 64bit but code wise it is still a pointer type, and it will get compiled accordingly. The compiled app will be either 32 or 64, but it will only compare objects generated by that compiled app, running on a given machine, and it will work correctly, simply comparing the pointer type.

Comment: I was talking about the *code* you posted. wrappers are indeed problematic unless done with a derivation schema, and your use of lambdas pretty-much takes that off the table. If the first version "worked" then why not use an unsigned 64-bit interlocked incremental? At  an average consumption rate of one-million objects per second, it would take approximately 580 *thousand* years before an overflow. I probably misunderstood what you're trying to do, though saving the address of "something" where that something can be "anything" callable seems somewhat futile.

Comment: @WhozCraig: that was just some quick psuedo-code; sorry for any confusion it may have brought up. also, I'm not using lambdas in this scheme. Wouldn't the 64-bit increment idea be unusable on a 32-bit machine (which I'm targeting with this "library")?

Comment: @Shokwav It is certainly not guaranteed to be defined on a 32bit platform, to be sure. Were there specific platforms you were targeting where it may *not* be available? (it is available on Windows 32bit and every distro of Linux, Debian, and OpenBSD I'm aware of in the last decade at least). If push came to shove you could also double-layer a `struct ID { uint32_t low; uint32_t high; };` and voodoo a double increment if needed. As both are unsigned overflow can be detected (`if (incr(&low) == 0) incr(&high);`). Hope that made sense. That should work almost everywhere.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's good to hear, about the wide availability. The struct solution is interesting; I may ultimately end up having to do something hackish like that.

Comment: @Shokwav for C++ its trivial to write the operators needed for equivalence, lesser,pre and post increment operators, etc For C you may need a `cmp_id`, `incr_id`, etc. api for those operations, but it has potential. Anyway, best of luck. Hope it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a regular pointer (let alone a function pointer) to `uint64_t` is implementation-defined, since pointers could be wider than 64 bits.  The conversion is well-defined if you use `uintptr_t` (and that type exists).

Converting a function pointer to any integer type is implementation-defined (even if you use `uintptr_t`), because function pointers may be wider than regular pointers.  Some other standards like POSIX explicitly allow this, so under POSIX it is safe to cast function pointers to data pointers like `void*` and to `uintptr_t`.

(Converting a pointer-to-member to an integer, data pointer, or regular function pointer is undefined, and in practice likely to always fail since they're bigger than regular pointers.)

However, it may be simpler to just use `uint64_t` instead of `size_t` for your unique IDs.  It is basically impossible to overflow a `uint64_t` by incrementing it repeatedly due to their enormous range.

Comment: So my suspicions are true. Thanks.